# Customize legend AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, canvas, chart.js

I want to draw a bar chart in AngularJS

This is my html:

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="datta" chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true">
                </canvas>
```

I haven't used much this chart library, but the idea is that I want to customize my legend and I want to declare an array with some data like

```
$scope.legend = ["item1", "item2"]
```

and this array is what I want to display below my chart. Is there some way to do this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is very unclear and far too limited for us to give a proper answer.

Comment: I want to display a legend for my chart like this: $scope.legend = ["item1", item2]. This is the array i want to display

Comment: I found some documentation about legends [here](http://carlcraig.github.io/tc-angular-chartjs/legend/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got it. If you're trying to set the legends of the graph you need to set it in the chart options, not setting chart-legend to true. You're html should be like:

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="datta" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="chart-options"></canvas>
```

Than you need to create a $scope.chart-options like:

```
$scope.chart-options = {
    legend: {
        display: true,
    },
};
```

You can have more info here: [Chartjs legend documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration)